# Add entity framework into project but don't see the table in the .edmx file

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

So I am having a weird issue with EF 5.0/ I open a connection to the Oracle database using visual studio just fine. Everything is all good. A few days ago, when I added the EF to my solution, after filtering out the connection so I can see the schema that I want, I can see the table in .edmx file. Now I made a new solution with another EF and using the same connection, I can see the tables that I need to add @ the final step of adding the EF, but the .edmx doesn't show the tables at all. It like blank... Is there any solutions for this as I looked up and down google and I don't see any case similar to mine at all.

Comment: check the Error tab, or right click the edmx -> open with -> xml, check any error

Comment: I managed to add it in. Seriously, I have no idea what going on... So on one instance, I can see only the SYS schema at the last step when adding EF, then I quit the EF adding. After that, I took a look at the filter of the connection, move every schema to the left, then move them all back to the right. Then voila, I can see the table of the schema that I wanted, and now they display the tables... It works but I have absolutely no clue what went wrong...